# Query/Procedure to get rows for only Ids having more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a Oracle table with person ID and other columns. And this Person ID can have one row or more rows.

Example tablename: inventory

```
personID   personName    type     bookname       itemnumber

101           aaa        Book      book1           2001
101           aaa        Book      book2           2002
105           mmm        Book      book3           2003
107           bbb        Book      book4           2006
107           bbb        Book      book5           2007
107           bbb         DVD       DVD1           7001
```

and so on....

```
Select * from inventory where type='Book';
```

will return 5 rows for ids 101,105 and 107.

But I want to omit id's that have only one row(105 in the above case), and I would like the sql query to return rows for only the IDs that have more than one row, in this case 101 and 107 and the corresponding values for these ids.
So result should be only four rows and not five. How can it be done?

Do I need to write a cursor for this or can anyone suggest a sample script for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM inventory
WHERE inventory.personID IN
(SELECT i.personID FROM inventory i 
WHERE i.type='Book' 
GROUP BY i.personID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1)x
AND inventory.type='Book'
```

Comment: Will this query work for Oracle PL/SQL or SQL Server? I will try it on Monday:-)